# What data provider for a tclientdataset using a csv file?

Tags: csv, c++builder

I have a tclientdataset.  It is used to get data to and from a csv file.  The csv file may not exist until the application is run.  I have the following code in a tbutton...

```
ClientDataSet1->FileName = "c:\\testdata.csv";
ClientDataSet1->Open();

 AddFiles(Edit1->Text);
 ClientDataSet1->SaveToFile("c:\\testdata.csv");
```

When I run the application I get a "Missing data providor or data packet" error.  I set the data provider to "Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)" and I still get the error.

What am I missing out or doing wrong?   I REALLY don't want to have to create a dsn or do any manual pre-run work.  I want the application to do all that.  so I can move it to another computer and it just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers so I'll answer and give an update.  I have been able to use the clientdata set succesfully.  I needed to create it with clientdataset->createdataset().

But it doesn't generate a CSV file.  It generates some other type of file.

If I could get it to generate a CSV file that would be ideal but for now I can stick with it working as it does.

Comment: Would XML work in place of a csv? recent versions of Delphi/C++Builder let you convert between arbitrary XML documents and the data packets that are used by a client dataset. Thus, the file-based approach can be used to work with XML documents as well as dedicated datasets.